# Create-next-app connectivity issue between my machine and GitHub

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, nvm

some ideas about this error ?

```
npx create-next-app --example i18n-routing i18n-app
Creating a new Next.js app in /home/j/i18n-app
Downloading files for example i18n-routing. This might take a moment.
? Could not download "i18n-routing" because of a connectivity issue between your machine and GitHub.
Do you want to use the default template instead? › (Y/n)
```

(ZSH, node v18.7.0, npm 8.18.0, I can use 'npm i someapps'...)

Answer (score 0):

I found, you have to make as if there were no problem and to make a npm i

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).